# Center image on canvas and resize of of 50% of canvas wdith

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm trying to center an image on canvas, but also resize the image so it's not 100%  of the canvas width. So for example, it currently looks like this:

[image: Example 1]

I can center the image, which the below code is doing, but when I try to resize it, it looks like this:

[image: Example 2]

I'd like to at-least have it, so there is padding around the canvas and the image is in the center.

```
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
        imgCenterWidth = canvas.width / 2 - img.width / 2;
        imgCenterHeight = canvas.height / 2 - img.height / 2
        ctx.drawImage(img, imgCenterWidth, imgCenterHeight, img.width * 0.7, img.height * 0.7);
    }
    img.src = parent.find('img').attr('src');

    <canvas id="editor-canvas" width=640 height=300>
    </canvas>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try using `imgCenterWidth = canvas.width / 2 - (img.width * 0.7)  / 2` and `imgCenterHeight = canvas.height / 2 - (img.height * 0.7)  /  2`

Comment: I believe you're calculating the centring before you resize, you need to use the resized image sizes in your `imgCenterWidth` and `imgCenterHeight` calculations.

Comment: Thanks, while this does work, it doesn't fit the image inside of the canvas. so I'd like to calculate the image width and height and make it smaller then the canvas height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned you wanted some padding around the image and you wanted to have it centered but not how much padding you wanted around the image so I made a function that takes an amount in padding and resizes the image to allow for that much padding around it.

Keep in mind though that unless you use a square canvas with a square image that only the width or height of the image are going to have that exact amount of padding between itself and the canvas.

So in the example below where I started with your canvas size and an image of dimensions 1280x720, the function keeps reducing the sides until they are smaller than the canvas + the padding while also staying proportional (because who wants distorted images?).

I hope this helps and if you have any questions or want any alterations feel free to ask.

```js
// Get a reference to our canvas and get the 2d
// context so we can draw an image onto it.
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

/**
 * The padding function figures out how much to reduce the image
 * by (if any amount) in order to make it fit onto the canvas width
 * the desired padding.
 *
 * @param {number} padding The least amount of padding to add to add to all sides of the image.
*/
function addImage(padding) {

  const img = new Image();

  // Wait for the image to load, just as you did in your
  // question sample code.
  img.onload = function () {
  
    while (img.width + padding > canvas.width || img.height + padding > canvas.height) {
    
      if (img.width + padding > canvas.width) {
      
        let newWidth = canvas.width - (padding * 2);
        
        img.height = Math.round((img.height / img.width) * newWidth);
        
        img.width = newWidth;
        
      }
      else if (img.height + padding > canvas.height) {
      
        let newHeight = canvas.height - (padding * 2);
        
        img.width = Math.round((img.width / img.height) * newHeight);
        
        img.height = newHeight;
      
      }
    
    }
    
    ctx.drawImage(img, canvas.width / 2 - img.width / 2, canvas.height / 2 - img.height / 2, img.width, img.height);

  };

  img.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/gOOrvAP.png';

}

addImage(20);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="300"></canvas>
```